# How to separate data frame in R into two separate data frames for Stepwise Regression in SuperLearner

Tags: r

I have a dataset 162 x 152. What I want to do is use stepwise regression, incorporating cross validation on the dataset to create a model and to test how accurate that model is.

```
ID  RT (seconds)    76_TI2  114_DECC    120_Lop 212_PCD 236_X3Av
4281    38  4.086   1.2 2.322   0   0.195
4952    40  2.732   0.815   1.837   1.113   0.13
4823    41  4.049   1.153   2.117   2.354   0.094
3840    41  4.049   1.153   2.117   3.838   0.117
3665    42  4.56    1.224   2.128   2.38    0.246
3591    42  2.96    0.909   1.686   0.972   0.138
```

This is part of the dataset I have. I want to construct a model where my Y variable is RT(seconds) and all my variables (my predictors) are all the other 151 variables in my dataset. I was told to use the superleaner package, and algorithm for that is:-

```
test <- CV.SuperLearner(Y = Y, X = X, V = 10, SL.library = SL.library,
verbose = TRUE, method = "method.NNLS")
```

The problem is that I'm still rather new to R. The main way in which I've been reading my data in and performing other forms of machine learning algorithms onto my data is by doing the following:-

```
mydata <- read.csv("filepathway")
fit <- lm(RT..seconds~., data=mydata)
```

So how do I go about separating the RT seconds column from the input of my data so that I can input the things as an X and Y dataframe? i.e something along the lines of:-

```
mydata <- read.csv("filepathway")
mydata$RT..seconds. = Y         #separating my Y response variable
Alltheother151variables = X     #separating all of my X predictor variables (all 151 of them)
SL.library <- c("SL.step")
test <- CV.SuperLearner(Y (i.e RT seconds column), X (all the other 151 variables that corresponds to the RT values), V = 10, SL.library = SL.library,
verbose = TRUE, method = "method.NNLS")
```

I hope this all makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the response variable is in the first column, you can simply use:

```
Y <- mydata[ ,  1 ]
X <- mydata[ , -1 ]
```

The first argument of `[` (the row number) is empty, so we keep all the rows, 
and the second is either `1` (the first column) or `-1` (everything but the first column).

If your response variable is elsewhere, you can use the column names instead:

```
Y <- mydata[ , "RT..seconds." ]
X <- mydata[ , setdiff( colnames(mydata), "RT..seconds." ) ]
```

Comment: Hey again, I was just wondering whether you could help me out again with a side issue. I've ran my data and done what you said, used 10 fold V with this equation:-
'test <- CV.SuperLearner(Y,X, V = 10, SL.library = SL.step, verbose = TRUE, method = "method.NNLS")'

But how do I get to see the values for my 10 folds, so I can see how close the test set data was to the training data set?